# When/How An Undirected Graph Can Be Recovered From Graph Laplacian

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, graph-laplacian

Let $L$ be a $d\times d$ symmetric positive definite matrix.  (When) does $L$ define a unique undirected graph?

Sorry if this is a basic question, I am *very* new to the field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a graph is loopless and contains no multiedges, its laplacian is always unique. Notice that the laplacian is a difference between matrices $D$ and $M$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing graph's degree sequence on the main diagonal and $M$ is the graph's adjacency matrix. $M$ is unique for any graph and for a simple graph it has zeros on the main diagonal, therefore for each simple graph its laplacian is also unique.

Comment: But how can the graph be reconstructed from the Laplacian?

Comment: If Laplacian is equal to $D-M$ and $M$ has zeros on the diagonal and $D$ is diagonal, you can easily get $M$ which is the graph's adjacency matrix. Then each row/column represents one vertex, and if there is an edge between vertices $i, j$, then $M_{i ,j}=1$